# Allocating memory for 3d array in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to determine what the best practice is for allocating memory for a 3d array in a constructor.

Currently I have:
region.h

```
#ifndef REGION_H
#define REGION_H

struct region_data
{ 
    unsigned char ID; 
    unsigned int data;
};

class region
{
    private:
        region_data * data;

    public:
        region(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z); 
        ~region();

};

#endif
```

and region.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "region.h"

region::region(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
{
    data = static_cast<region_data*>(malloc( sizeof(region_data) * x * y * z ));
}
```

However, I know I'm making the mistake of using malloc in c++. What is a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here? I am aware of triply nested vectors, but I want to learn a way to do this without vectors, mainly for the sake of learning here, partially to avoid the overhead of a vector (as minimal as it is) and partially because the syntax for triply nested vectors is verbose and ugly!

Please feel free to mention any other mistakes I have made as well. :)

Thanks!!

Edit:
Duplicate shows answers for C, but not for C++.

Edit 2:
Question is not asking how to access array, but how to allocate it.

Edit 3:
The "ugly" syntax in question is:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<region_data> > > data;
```

is somewhat difficult to read IMO. Also, filling the 3d array with empty data is very ugly, but that might need to be its own question. Let's not get too hung up on trying to get me to use a vector please, I would prefer that people simply answer my original question.

Edit 4:
Trying to use a vector, here's the fill code. Blech.

```
void region::fill(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
{
    std::vector< std::vector< region_data > > temp;
    std::vector< region_data > temp2;
    region_data temp3;
    temp3.ID=0;
    temp3.data=0;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<z; k++)
            {
                temp2.push_back(temp3);
            }
        temp.push_back(temp2);
        }
    data.push_back(temp);
    }    
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<region_data>`. That will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: "but I want to learn a way to do this without vectors". The C++-malloc is *new*. `new new[] delete delete[]` ...

Comment: Then use `new` to implement a dynamic array class, and use that for storage.

Comment: ...and even in C, mapping a 3dim array manually to 1dim is not (always) necessary.

Comment: `partially because the syntax for triply nested vectors is verbose and ugly`  You can use `[][][]` for a triply nested vector, just like a 3 dimensional array.  So I don't know what this "verbose and ugly" syntax you speak of.

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to allocate. The chosen answer how to access. The question is in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is a duplicate indeed, right?

Comment: @karlphillip Yes, I think so.